# Android - TextInputLayout has a set width (160dp) and a hint. When I go look at it, the width isn't 160dp. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: android

So I've been following [the official docs from Google]https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-polished-user-experience#2.
Here's my code.

```
<ConstraintLayout ...>
...
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cost_of_service"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/cost_of_service_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
...

</ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: What I see]

[image: What I should see]

As you can see I have my android:layout_width="160dp" and android:hint="some hint", but I don't get to see it when I run it. Is there anything I could do to show the TextInputLayout as 160dp?

Comment: Please try changing your TextInputEditText  android:layout_width="wrap_content" to "match_parent".

Comment: This was it. Thanks, I feel so silly

Answer (score 0):

change TextInputEditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent"

```
<ConstraintLayout ...>
...
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/cost_of_service"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cost_of_service_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
...

</ConstraintLayout>
```